# How to sort this list in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I've got a list of imported broken links. I need to sort the list based on column C (the error code) so I can find all links with error 404. However, I need to know the corresponding parent page (column A) for all the links. The problem is that the parent page in column A is only listed once before all its corresponding links are listed below it in column B.

I assume I need to somehow copy down the values in column A until you reach the next URL, and then copy that down and so fourth for all of column A. Is there a way I can do this fairly easily? It's a huge spreadsheet so manually is out of the question.

Below is a screenshot of part of the spreadsheet:

[image]

Comment: How many rows are in the entire spreadsheet?

Comment: There's 2202 rows in the spreadsheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I'd try, conceptually:

Insert another column B. In that column, first row, copy current A1. For the rest, use a conditional formula: =IF(A2="", B1, A2). If A is blank, copy the value above. If A is not blank, use it. This should give you the appropriate value from A on each row.

Copy that new column and paste values onto itself.

Do your sort, delete the rows with the A value that are otherwise empty.

Comment: That's pretty creative.

Comment: That's a useful pattern for many situations where you are taking data that is formatted for reading and want to make it a sortable/filterable table. "Paste Values" is a key feature to know in Excel.